# Нерассмотренный или не рассмотренный

Tags: слитно-раздельно

С 1 октября запущен канал нерассмотренных агентом программ, предусмотренный системой.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде же бы раздельно, если есть зависимое слово? Не рассмотренных (кем?) агентом. Насколько знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь - раздельно. Хотя сама фраза небезгрешна стилистически, но мотивов для слитного написания не просматривается.

> Вроде же бы раздельно, если есть зависимое слово?

Есть такое правило. Оно не абсолютно, но здесь вполне применимо. Хотя на самом деле автор вправе отступить от этого правила, если четко понимает, зачем и почему это он делает. Такое бывает очень редко, обычно это диктуется тем, что слово используется в каком-то особом, авторском значении, которое отличается от простого отрицания данного качества или свойства - или же без отрицания неупотребимо вовсе. В стилистически нейтральных, не художественных тестах подобное тем более не приветствуется.

Я бы еще одно практическое правило привнес. Если есть хоть малейший повод усомниться  - пиши раздельно. Это не ошибка в любом случае. А если и ошибка, то не такая грубая, как в обратной ситуации.

Comment: мне интуитивно кажется что если автор имеет в виду что "программы не были рассмотрены" автором, то пишется раздельно, а если что "они были нерассмотрены им" - тогда слитно. второе маловероятно, потому и редко. мне даже браузерный спелчекер подчёркивает второй вариант